# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on showing the splash screen/company logo after restarting

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my system and yesterday I restarted the system, but since then it is showing the manufacturer's logo. See the image below.

[image: Ubuntu stuck on manufacturer's logo]

I have tried forced shutdown many a times but it has also not helped me in getting out of this situation.

What can I do now?

Comment: Every time you force you PC to stop, I assume by the power button you can do damage to the file system this does not help your problem but may make it far worse. What did you do before it started freezing?

Comment: @David Many a thanks for the reply,    Actually I wanted to connect my wireless earphone with my laptop ACER Ubuntu-20.04 .  But  the BLUETOOTH ON option was not visible in the settings.  so i tried fixing it by using some commands available in the internet.   Now when I restarted the System to get it going. since then my system is in freezed state. Any help would be highly welcome.

Comment: You need to add this info to the question, no where in the question do you mention Bluetooth Also add to the questions the exact steps and commands you did to try and fix it..

Comment: It may be more convenient to reinstall Ubuntu than trying to fix this error (assuming you are quite new to Ubuntu).